# React Native FAILURE: Build failed with an exception ative_modules.gradle' line: 191

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i got error when i start "react-native run-android"

do anyone can help me ?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 191
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'app'.

  > Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

  The current character read is 'E' with an int value of 69
  Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
  line number 1
  index number 0
  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/Users/wayan/Desktop/android/app/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:795:3)    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:288:41)    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:267:20)    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:276:17)    at GlobSync._processReaddir (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:137:22)    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:132:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:380:10)    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:383:10)    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 191
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'app'.

  > Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

  The current character read is 'E' with an int value of 69
  Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
  line number 1
  index number 0
  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/Users/wayan/Desktop/android/app/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:795:3)    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:288:41)    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:267:20)    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:276:17)    at GlobSync._processReaddir (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:137:22)    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:132:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:380:10)    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:383:10)    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
  ^
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `android/app/build/intermediates/signin-config/debug/out/` and delete `signin-config.json`. Use your file explorer because it might be hidden by your code editor. I couldn't see mine in VS Code. After deletion, run `react-native run-android` again. It might fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I can not comment yet so hoping this may fix your problem.

Did you upgrade your React-Native recently? It seems to be a problem with your cli tools not being able to find the root of your android folder. In a nutshell, all you have to (hopefully that's the issue) do is, add the `sourceDir` to your `native.config.js`.

This would be a good time to mention that `link` will deprecate the use of `rnpm` in your `package.json` file. As the documentation suggests, you will have to create a new file (if not already) in your project root directory.

So in your project root directory, create a new file named `native.config.js`. And inside the folder, you may define the `sourceDir` which will link to your android folder of the project.

Like so:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {
    //This link will change according to your android file location. That is if you have a custom directory
    "sourceDir": "./android/app/src",

    //Additionally, you could define the package name
    "packageName":"com.wayan.app"

    },
  },
  //assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

So suppose your android folder is called something else, you can replace the `sourceDir` with the link to your `android/app/src` directory.

Now try `react-native link` and re-try `react-native run-android`

Going through your code, the line says `Script 'C:\Users\wayan\Desktop\android\app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 191`. So I am assuming that your project name is called app inside android folder?

Here is the **[LINK](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md)** to the official guide for autolink. Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @Mohammed Ahmed, I love you man, you saved my life, thank you so much